# Reference build.gradle versionName attribute in xml layout

Tags: android

I'd like to have a layout file which references the `versionName` attribute in my gradle file:

```
...
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "se.test.myapp"
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 22
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
....
```

Something like

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/versionName"
    />
```

Is there a neat way to to this, without having to set up the layout in my code?

Comment: Just in case anyone needs, to reference `versionName` in Java code, one can use `BuildConfig.VERSION_NAME`.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

According to http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system you can create resources directly from gradle, so putting

```
android {
...
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "se.test.myapp"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    ...
    applicationVariants.all { variant ->    
        variant.resValue "string", "versionName", variant.versionName
    }
    ...
}
```

in your build.gradle will do the trick

It creates resource file `generated.xml` during compilation in `generated/res` folder which is included alongside with resources provided by you in values folder. So you can use `android:text="@string/versionName"` to reference this value. Unfortunately, sometimes IDE can't resolve this reference, so it'll look like an error in your layout resource (while it's a valid statement and will be resolved at runtime).

You can suppress the error by clicking inside the "@string/versionName", then Alt+Enter, in the menu select "Create string value resource 'versionName", then "Suppress for tag".

Comment: Thanks for this! Could you please explain in more detail on how I would apply this, and how it works? I guess it creates a string variable for me, but how do I reference it in my TextView element?

Comment: It creates resource file `generated.xml` during compilation in `generated/res` folder which is included alongside with resources provided by you in `values` folder. So you can use `android:text="@string/versionName"` to reference this value. Unfortunately, sometimes IDE can't resolve this reference, so it'll look like an error in your layout resource (while it's a valid statement and will be resolved in runtime).

Comment: I noticed the error, but as you said, it was resolved at runtime. Very nice answer, working like a charm! Appreciated.

Comment: Might be worth referencing the comment in the answer, or adding it. Nice bit of information.

Comment: You can suppress the error by clicking inside the "@string/versionName", then Alt+Enter, in menu select  "Create string value resource 'versionName", then "Suppress for tag".

Answer (score 5):

Edit: You should not use Jack only for this. As per [the official announcement](https://source.android.com/source/jack) **Jack is deprecated** (for everything except Java 8 features).

I used a string resource:

```
<resources>
    <string name="app_ver" translatable="false">1.0.2</string>
    ...
</resources>
```

in the app's build.gradle:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        ...
        versionName "@string/app_ver"
        jackOptions {
            enabled true        
        }
    }
...
}
```

And like this:

```
<Preference
    android:title="Version"
    android:summary="@string/app_ver"/>
```

[This](https://github.com/EmmanuelMess/Simple-Accounting/tree/v1.4.4) project in GitHub contains a working version of this.

Comment: I liked your solution, but did it stop working? [EmmanuelMess/Simple-Accounting@6851fa3](https://github.com/EmmanuelMess/Simple-Accounting/commit/6851fa3fc2fc88354ba35e1da3c8a4eeea3dcd7a)

Comment: @AntonioViniciusMenezesMedei You should not use this solution, read the note.

Comment: You shouldn't use this anymore.

Answer (score 1):

I use variables in my projects for versionName and versionCode

for example, in the app's build.gradle:

```
final VERSION_NAME = '2.2.3'
final VERSION_CODE = 15

android {
    defaultConfig {
        resValue "string", "version_code", VERSION_NAME + " (build " + VERSION_CODE + ")"
        versionCode VERSION_CODE
        versionName VERSION_NAME
        ...
    }
...
}
```

Android Studio automatically generates an untranslatable string resource:

```
<string name="version_code" translatable="false">2.2.3 (build 15)</string>
```

which I can use in xml:

```
<Preference
    android:selectable="false"
    android:title="@string/version"
    android:summary="@string/version_code" />
```

hope it will be useful

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can set the VersionName in your android manifest with a string resource, too. Like this:

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
android:versionName="@string/versionName"
```

**Your Layout xml**

```
android:text="@string/versionName"
```

But I do not know how compatible this is to gradle.