# Android Studio cannot find resources when building for device with version > 5.0

Tags: android, gradle

I found a strange behavior with my project when I try to build it for an android device with Android version > to 5.0 (lollipop) under linux.

The error message is:

```
Error:(5, 28) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'versionName' with value '@string/Application_Version').
```

The message points to my AndroidManifest.xml file which contains this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="net.testApplication"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="@string/Application_Version"
      split="lib_dependencies_apk">
</manifest>
```

When I test my application on devices below 5.1 it works as expected without any warning/error (as the string ***Application_Version*** exists and is perfectly found) but when I try a device (real or emulated) with 5.1 or greater, it throws me this message.

I updated my Android Studio to 2.3 recently and since it produces this error message. With AS 2.2 I hadn't any problem...

I already tried to fix this by doing things I found on SO with similar issues, like clean cache and restart, delete building files manually, cleaning my project using ./gradlew clean and re-importing my project but nothing seems to work until now.

Answer (score 1):

According to this issue:
https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=235893

You have to move versionName into app/build.gradle file. And If you want to access versionName in an xml layout file according this StackOverflow question:
[Reference build.gradle versionName attribute in xml layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29524583/reference-build-gradle-versionname-attribute-in-xml-layout)

You should do this:

```
    android {
...
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "se.test.myapp"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    ...
    applicationVariants.all { variant ->    
        variant.resValue "string", "versionName", variant.versionName
    }
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well after some testings, it seems to be related to the ***Instant Run*** feature... As soon as I deactivated it, everything worked as expected.