# Android Studio 2.3: can't use string resource in android:versionName

Tags: android

I upgraded Android Studio 2.2 -> 2.3 today and now have a compiler error when building my app in Android Studio that I didn't have before.

```
Error:No resource found that matches the given name (at 'versionName' with value '@string/BRAND_VERSION').
```

This is the string resource.

```
<string name="BRAND_VERSION">2.0</string>
```

This is the relevant section from the manifest.

```
<manifest package="com.metaswitch.cp.unbrandedpackage"
      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
      android:versionCode="5"
      android:versionName="@string/BRAND_VERSION">
```

According to [Android documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/versioning.html), string resources are allowed in the versionName in the manifest or in build.gradle.

This is not specific to my app.  I can repro with this [Android sample](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture/tree/todo-mvp-loaders/)

It builds and installs fine for me.  When I make this single line change to the versionName in build.gradle (picking a random string resource from strings.xml) it fails with the same error.

```
// versionName "1.0"
versionName "@string/add_task"
```

This is the build.gradle from the Android sample (note my edit to versionName).

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion
    buildToolsVersion rootProject.ext.buildToolsVersion

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.android.architecture.blueprints.todomvploaders"
    minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
    targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
    versionCode 1
    // I really want to use a string resource here!
    // versionName "1.0"
    versionName "@string/add_task"

    testInstrumentationRunner 'android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner'
}

buildTypes {
    debug {
        minifyEnabled true
        // Uses new built-in shrinker http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/built-in-shrinker
        useProguard false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        testProguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguardTest-rules.pro'
    }

    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        useProguard true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        testProguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguardTest-rules.pro'
    }
}

// If you need to add more flavors, consider using flavor dimensions.
productFlavors {
    mock {
        applicationIdSuffix = ".mock"
    }
    prod {

    }
}

// Remove mockRelease as it's not needed.
android.variantFilter { variant ->
    if(variant.buildType.name.equals('release')
            && variant.getFlavors().get(0).name.equals('mock')) {
        variant.setIgnore(true);
    }
}

// Always show the result of every unit test, even if it passes.
testOptions.unitTests.all {
    testLogging {
        events 'passed', 'skipped', 'failed', 'standardOut', 'standardError'
    }
}
buildToolsVersion '25.0.0'
```

}

```
/*
 Dependency versions are defined in the top level build.gradle file. This helps keeping track of
 all versions in a single place. This improves readability and helps managing project complexity.
 */
dependencies {
    // App's dependencies, including test
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:$rootProject.supportLibraryVersion"
    compile "com.android.support:cardview-v7:$rootProject.supportLibraryVersion"
    compile "com.android.support:design:$rootProject.supportLibraryVersion"
    compile "com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:$rootProject.supportLibraryVersion"
    compile "com.android.support:support-v4:$rootProject.supportLibraryVersion"
    compile "com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-idling-resource:$rootProject.espressoVersion"
    compile "com.google.guava:guava:$rootProject.guavaVersion"
// Dependencies for local unit tests
testCompile "junit:junit:$rootProject.ext.junitVersion"
testCompile "org.mockito:mockito-all:$rootProject.ext.mockitoVersion"
testCompile "org.hamcrest:hamcrest-all:$rootProject.ext.hamcrestVersion"

// Android Testing Support Library's runner and rules
androidTestCompile "com.android.support.test:runner:$rootProject.ext.runnerVersion"
androidTestCompile "com.android.support.test:rules:$rootProject.ext.runnerVersion"

// Dependencies for Android unit tests
androidTestCompile "junit:junit:$rootProject.ext.junitVersion"
androidTestCompile "org.mockito:mockito-core:$rootProject.ext.mockitoVersion"
androidTestCompile 'com.google.dexmaker:dexmaker:1.2'
androidTestCompile 'com.google.dexmaker:dexmaker-mockito:1.2'

// Espresso UI Testing
androidTestCompile "com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:$rootProject.espressoVersion"
androidTestCompile "com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-contrib:$rootProject.espressoVersion"
androidTestCompile "com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-intents:$rootProject.espressoVersion"

// Resolve conflicts between main and test APK:
androidTestCompile "com.android.support:support-annotations:$rootProject.supportLibraryVersion"
androidTestCompile "com.android.support:support-v4:$rootProject.supportLibraryVersion"
androidTestCompile "com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:$rootProject.supportLibraryVersion"
androidTestCompile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:$rootProject.supportLibraryVersion"
androidTestCompile "com.android.support:design:$rootProject.supportLibraryVersion"
```

}

Comment: The value of 'minSdkVersion' is only used if it is not specified in the build.gradle build scripts.When specified in the Gradle build scripts, the menifest value is ignored and can be misleading, so should be removed to avoid ambiguity.

Comment: post your `build.gradle`

Comment: Its working fine for me.

Comment: How is minSdkVersion relevant here?  This problem is with versionName and reproduces for me with versionName in build.gradle only.

Comment: I have never tried referencing a string resource in Gradle, so I am not surprised that `versionName "@string/add_task"` might have issues. Note that this is a different string resource than is `@string/BRAND_VERSION`. With regards to the manifest value, [there has been one bug report](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=235893), but it needs a reproducible test case. Unfortunately, I am not in position to try to reproduce this problem this week. If you can, upload a sample project that reproduces the problem to that issue, to try to move that along.

Comment: Thanks, I have posted a repro scenaio there.  And someone else already posted another.

Comment: I've answered this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42604987/android-studio-cannot-find-resources-when-building-for-device-with-version-5-0/42681733#42681733

Comment: Google are working on a fix: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=235893#c8

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem after upgrading Android Studio. Turning off instant run in preferences helped the app to run again.

Comment: wow! I could never imagine this would be the root cause. I too had the exact same error and it went away when I disabled the instant run....
weird on Google's part!

Answer (score 0):

With reference to [Google issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37137338),This has been **fixed**. This is available with **Android studio 3.0.0-alpha6 build**.

If any issue persists, please report at [Google issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37137338) they will re-open to examine.