# How to add app version on Android (React Native) splash screen using react-native-splash-screen library

Tags: android, react-native, splash-screen

I am using react-native-splash-screen library to show the simple splash screen of our react native app. I am quite not sure how to go about adding the app version on the same splash screen.

Here is the layout file -
**launch_screen.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:background="@drawable/background_splash"
      android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/appVersion"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:text="V0.0.0"
        android:textColor="#f00"
        android:textSize="25sp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Here is the drawable -
**background_splash.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:drawable="@color/splashscreen_bg"/>
    <item
        android:drawable="@mipmap/splash_icon"
        android:gravity="center" />
</layer-list>
```

MainActivity file where I am fetching the latest app version and setting that on textView but It is throwing an error -> ****Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference.****

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends ReactActivity {
static String currentLocale;
    /**
     * Avoiding the blank screen between splash and app
     */
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {  
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        SplashScreen.show(this);

        Context context = this.getApplicationContext();
        PackageManager packageManager = context.getPackageManager();
        String packageName = context.getPackageName();

        String appVersion = "not available"; // initialize String

        try {
              appVersion = packageManager.getPackageInfo(packageName, 0).versionName;
        } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
        }

        TextView appVersionName = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.appVersion);
        try {
            appVersionName.setText(appVersion);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),e.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        MainActivity.currentLocale = getResources().getConfiguration().locale.toString();
    }


}



}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the Gradle plugin/Android Studio, version code and version name are available statically in BuildConfig
***(You can check your app level build.gradle file)***

It should looks something like this

```
defaultConfig {
 versionCode 1
 versionName "1.0"
}
```

So you can simply get your App versionName and versionCode using `YOUR_PACKAGE_NAME.BuildConfig`

Here you go:

```
import your_package_name_here.BuildConfig;
```

Inside `onCreate` method

```
int versionCode = BuildConfig.VERSION_CODE;
String versionName = BuildConfig.VERSION_NAME;
```

Thanks :)

Comment: Thanks, Dinesh for your answer. I am able to get the app version but I am not sure how I can show that on splash screen, setText is throwing an error as mentioned in the description.

Answer (score 0):

**Approach**

Create a string resource file at compile-time, which will be used in TextView to show the app version.

**Step - (1)**
We can use gradle to create string resource so here are the changes in the gradle file -

```
android {
...
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.myapp"
        minSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    ...
    applicationVariants.all { variant ->    
       // This will generate versionName string resource.
       // We going to use same generated resource to show app version on splash screen.
       variant.resValue "string", "versionName", "v" + variant.versionName
    }
    ...
}
```

This will create a resource file `generated.xml` during compilation in `generated/res`. for more detail check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29524583/reference-build-gradle-versionname-attribute-in-xml-layout) by OleGG.

**Step - (2)**
**launch_screen.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:background="@drawable/background_splash"
      android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/appVersion"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="@string/versionName" />

</RelativeLayout>
```